# Generating surface of Kernel Density Estimates over time

Tags: time-series, python, density

I have a 1-minutely OHLC dataset indexed by time as follows:

```
df_ohlc
Out[2]: 
                      open  high  low  close  index  week
Date                                                    
2011-09-13 09:53:00   5.8   6.0  5.8    6.0      1     1
2011-09-13 09:54:00   6.0   6.0  6.0    6.0      2     1
2011-09-13 09:55:00   6.0   6.0  6.0    6.0      3     1
2011-09-13 09:56:00   6.0   6.0  6.0    6.0      4     1
2011-09-13 09:57:00   6.0   6.0  6.0    6.0      5     1
...
2017-07-17 18:19:00  2176.99  2176.99  2176.50  2176.50  3073467   305
2017-07-17 18:20:00  2175.00  2177.65  2175.00  2176.99  3073468   305
2017-07-17 18:21:00  2177.80  2177.84  2173.71  2177.61  3073469   305
2017-07-17 18:22:00  2177.50  2177.50  2175.04  2175.04  3073470   305
2017-07-17 18:23:00  2177.30  2177.30  2175.00  2175.00  3073471   305
```

In Python,

```
for i in range(1,len(df_ohlc)+1):
  plt.clf()
  kde_est.iloc[i] = df_ohlc['close'][df_ohlc['week']==i].plot.kde()
  plt.show()
```

generates the Kernel Density Estimate (a smooth histogram essentially) for each week's closing prices of the dataset. In other words, it generates 305 individual KDE plots for this dataset.

**How would I plot all these KDEs over time on one 3-Dimensional surface?**

For example, right now each KDE plot is [Close Price] x [Probability Density]. I'd like to introduce a new variable (z = time) so we can see the changes in KDE over time, [Close Price] x [Probability Density] x [Week]

Comment: Have you had a look at the matplotlib 3d examples?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way is

1) To write manually a function, that takes an array(this corresponds to your data during a week), either with hands, using a kernel you want $f(x)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{k=1}^n K((x-x_i)/hn)$, or using **scipy.stats.gaussian_kde**(or more general using **sklearn.neighbors** **KernelDensity**).

2) Merge the results of 1) into 1 array, say Prob.

3) Using the corresponging methods of matplotlib (**plot_surface**, etc) plot as you said [Price]x[Prob]x[Week]